# How import python script that requires command line arguments before importing?

Tags: python, python-unittest, aws-glue

Hi am trying to unit test a python script that requires command line arguments. This class is an AWS glue job but still pure python.

Here is my unit test:

```
import sys
import unittest

import src.UnzipFile # Fails Here


class TestUnzipFile(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_unzipping_file(self):

        """
        Tests that it can unzip a tar.gz file
        """


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        unittest.main()
    except Exception:
        TestUnzipFile().tearDownClass()
```

Here is the beginning of the script that I am trying to import (short version):

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,

                              [
                                  's3_bucket',
                                  'archive_path',
                                  'destination_path',
                              ])

bucket_name = args['s3_bucket']

tar_file_path = args['archive_path']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error after trying to import the script:

```
awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: --s3_bucket, --archive_path, --destination_path,
```

There is not a lot of documentation on unit testing of AWS glue jobs, and when a glue job is setup you cant use environment variables. Whatever parameters you want to use have to be arguments. So my question becomes how can I import a python script that requires arguments to be passed in?

Comment: it doesn't look like `class` but like normal code. You should put it in function so you could run it with arguments after importing - `src.UnzipFile.my_function(sys.argv)`. And in original file you should also run it as `my_function(sys.argv)`

Comment: Hey furas, thank you for replying your right its not a class just a normal script Ill edit my question. The problem I have is that the unit test fails as soon as it tries to import it

Comment: BTW: in one file I would do `sys.argv.append('--s3_bucket')` `sys.argv.append('--archive_path')` but I don't know if it will work for imported code. But normally I put code in function so I can  do `my_function(sys.argv)` or `my_function(['--s3_bucket', '--archive_path', '--destination_path'])` and it resolves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to step 5 in this [doc](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/tips-aws-glue-libs-gluepytest/). He did faced the exact issue and had a work around where you need to put the Glue side code in a function and write the following code so that it is executed only when its own code is called as an entry point as shown below :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

P.S : The blog is in Japanese and you can convert it to English to understand it better.